# how to send email attachments using power automate to webapi

Tags: power-automate

I am new to power automate. I need to read my email attachments and send each attachment to webapi as base64. I used below expression to convert email attachment to base64. but flow shows error as "Correct to include a valid reference to 'Get_Attachment_(V3)' for the input parameter(s) of action 'HTTP'.

what should be correct expression to convert attachment to base64.

**expression**:  base64(body('Get_Attachment_(V3)')?['contentBytes'])

error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

**Firstly**, in your JSON body, you just need to put quotes around the value of the `content` property.

[image: Body]

**Secondly**, make sure you have a `Get Attachment (V#)` step prior to the `HTTP` action.

This step actually retrieves the contents of the attachment.

[image: Get Attachment]

Comment: didn't help same error.

Comment: Can you show us the error with a screenshot?

Comment: {
  "$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
  "$content": "@{base64(body('Get_Attachment_(V3)')?['contentBytes'])}"
}

Comment: error attached in main thread.

Comment: Hang on ... where is the Get Attachment (V3) action in your screen shot?  In your loop, you should have that before calling the HTTP action, is that in place?  Can you show a screenshot of that entire section of the flow?

Comment: Added entire section of the flow..

Comment: That's your problem, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Try that now, that has to work.

Comment: 1. double quote didn't help. raw input shows "$content": "base64(body('Get_Attachment_(V3)')?['contentBytes'])". it failed. then without double quote it ran. but the content value not exact pdf. I tried to convert $content to pdf, it seems to be invalid file.